# Move all events out of the designer

Tags: c#, events

I have a form with many controls, each having events (and their handlers), total some tens events .
I found out that many times, due to complex combinations, events are being fired while the controls are being initiated, mainly because I load saved settings from my settings file that may change the default controls' initial settings, causing events to fire.

To avoid this, I moved all my events to a special method (in Main) that is being called only after all controls have been built and and set.

**It works fine, but the question is if this is good or common practice and what drawbacks it may have.**

I have also tried to move the events to a special Maim subclass, but could not find a way to get access to the private controls from the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are expecting as an answer here. If the code works well enough, and is reasonably clear, I can't really see the problem.

Furthermore, it sounds as if this is necessary in your case: If you need to set up or modify controls based on saved state from settings, then it seems clear that this needs to be done before you can add events for those controls. As I already mentioned: As long as your code works fine, and is clear and easy to understand, it should be OK (the latter point matters because it means you will be able to fix it without too much hassle if it should prove to be problematic for some unforeseen reason later).

**PS:** If you want some more feedback about this, then you should add some actual code to comment on. That however, would probably imply that this question is better suited for the [CodeReview StackExchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for this site. Perhaps you should add code, and post the question there instead.